# LVM: pvcreate by uuid or non "dev/sdX" method

Tags: linux, hard-disk, lvm, block-device

Is it possible to pvcreate a pv by any more unique means than the standard "/dev/sdX"?

The reason is the external multiple hard drive dock and dev mapper on my system don't always assign the same "/dev/sdX" at boot.  I work around this with ext4 mounts in fstab by mounting by uuid, otherwise the results could be disastrous reads/writes to the wrong disk.

Comment: That's not an obvious reason in itself.  Typically pvcreate is a one-off operation.  Re-numbering the disks afterwards won't cause any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use any of the names that appear up with the command as follows.

```
ll /dev/disk/by-*
```

Which are obviously symlinks to the corresponding `/dev/sdx` device again.

Comment: not `by-path` though :-P

Comment: and presumably not `by-uuid`.  Which leaves `partuuid` (if using GPT) and `by-id`, particularly `by-id/wwn-*` if possible, and again presumably not `lvm-pv-uuid-*`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to read the `man lvm.conf` manpage for a full explanation but your LVM filter is probably set up to ignore the disks. On my system it's set to `filter = [ "a/.*/" ]` which *adds* (hence the `a`) anything that matches the given regexp (which is `/.*/`, i.e everything). Your LVM filter may include some rejects (which would be indicates by a `r`).